Next.js server component not waiting for async function to reassign var
I am attempting to pull data asynchronously from the Az package into a Next.js 14 server component.
This is my page.js:
import MyServerComponent from "../components/MyServerComponent.js";

export default async function Home(){
  return(
    <main>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <MyServerComponent />
    </main>
  );
} 


And this is MyServerComponent.js:
import * as Az from "az";

// Server Component (MyServerComponent.js)

export default async function MyServerComponent() {

let tokens = await Az.Tokens('Мама мыла раму').done();
console.log("the tokens source is: ", tokens[0]);

let parses = "";
Az.Morph.init('./node_modules/az/dicts', async function() {
        let parses = await Az.Morph('школа');
        console.log(parses); // => 6 вариантов разбора
        console.log(parses[0].tag.toString()); // => 'VERB,perf,intr plur,past,indc'
      });

      console.log(parses);

    return (
        <>
<p>{tokens[0].source}</p>
<p>{parses[0].tag.toString()}</p>

</>
    );

  }

When I run the app, the component waits for tokens to populate asynchronously before rendering the text to the page. However, when I try to do the same for parses, I get a runtime error "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tag')." The component has no issues logging the pulled data to the console for either tokens or parses. Why isn't declaring parses in the outer scope and then reassigning it asynchronously within Az.Morph not working?
I've been wrestling with this one for a while. Please let me know what additional info I can provide.

This is not a nextjs problem. You’re assigning parses inside a callback that is not awaited. Adding async into the callback does not magically makes it being awaited.
